# Make an enum INSTANCE private

Tags: java, singleton, enums, private

I am using an enum singletom pattern like this:

```
public enum LicenseLoader implements ClientLicense {
    INSTANCE;

    /**
     * @return an instance of ClientLicense
     */
    public static ClientLicense getInstance() {
        return (ClientLicense)INSTANCE;
    }

   ...rest of code

}
```

Now I want to return the Interface and hide the fact that we are actually using an enum at all.  I want the client to use getInstance() and not LicenseLoader.INSTANCE as one day I may decide to use a different pattern if necessary.

Is is possible to make INSTANCE private to the enum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about making a `public interface` and `private enum` that `implements` said interface, with a singleton `INSTANCE` constant?

So, something like this (all in one class for brevity):

```
public class PrivateEnum {

    public interface Worker {
        void doSomething();
    }

    static private enum Elvis implements Worker {
        INSTANCE;
        @Override public void doSomething() {
            System.out.println("Thank you! Thank you very much!");
        }
    }

    public Worker getWorker() {
        return Elvis.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

This way, you're not exposing `Elvis.INSTANCE` (or even `enum Elvis` at all), using an `interface` to define your functionality, hiding all implementation details.

Comment: This worked perfectly, it allowed me to make the Worker package private also allowing me to get at some stuff I wanted to keep private to the outside world but available inside the package context.

Comment: The `enum` instance is still available, as I explained.

Answer (score 1):

All `enum` constants are accessible. For instance through deserialisation or the `enum`-specific reflective methods.

**As always, I strongly suggest avoiding singletons.**

Comment: You are giving bad advice.  "The enum singleton pattern provides an ironclad guarantee against multiple instantiation, even in the face of sophisticated serialization or reflection attacks." (Effective Java - Joshua Bloch)

Comment: No, I'm not giving you bad advice.

Comment: @Tom: what do you mean it's "still available" (comment to my answer)? `private` accessibility modifier on the `enum` is not ironclad (e.g. `setAccessible` attack), but this is true of every `class`, not just `enum`.

Comment: @polygenelubricants You can read the instance with `ObjectInputStream.readObject`. Also methods such as `Enum.valueOf`.

Comment: @Tom: a naive `Enum.valueOf` wouldn't work since the `private enum` is inaccessible. You can break this, of course, just like you can break anything `private`. I don't think there's anything specific to `enum` that makes it more vulnerable than any other `class` if an attacker is determined. In fact, I think it's harder to attack due to some built-in reflection defense etc.

Comment: @polygenelubricants Works for me! `public class Priv {    private enum En { THING } } class Pub {     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {         Class clazz = Class.forName("Priv$En");         System.err.println(Enum.valueOf(clazz, "THING"));    } }`

Comment: @Tom Besides, where are the multiple instances, hence, the singleton pattern!  Accessibility is not part of the singleton pattern so your comment, "As always, I strongly suggest avoiding singletons.", is deceiving.

Comment: @jax Singletons are evil. From google http://accu.org/index.php/articles/337 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scottdensmore/archive/2004/05/25/140827.aspx